# Subtracting 1 month to 2015-12-31 gives 2015-12-01

Tags: javascript, date, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract one month from `2015-12-31` but it gives me `2015-12-01` instead of `2015-11-30`. Why ?

Code:

```
var date1 = new Date('2015-12-31');
var date2 = new Date(date1);

date2.setMonth(date1.getMonth() - 1);
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);
```

Output:

```
Thu Dec 31 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Tue Dec 01 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Any workaround?

Comment: Well, you're technically trying to use November 31st the way you are doing it, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I get `Mon Nov 30 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Comment: @j08691, which is UTC Dec 1 2015 00:00:00

Comment: @Devon Then what is the right way to do?

Comment: What is your desired output? The last day of the previous month?

Comment: Are you able to use `moment`?  http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Flawyte, there isn't a way without writing conditions to handle this.  I'd recommend momentjs as well which is a library that will handle this for you.

Comment: Are you working with the "last day of the month" or "the 31st"?  IE should subtracting 1 month from the 31st december be the same as subtracting 1 month from 30th december or 1st january?  It has to be one or the other - you can't have it both ways...

Comment: I don't like the idea of using a whole library just to subtract one month. There must be a vanilla solution...

Comment: moment.js has so much fat on it

Comment: The fastest you can pretend to accomplish (or the fastest I could pretend to think) is check whether the new date's month is the same as the current one. If so, subtract one day from it. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/88pcLtgw/1/ (Thouth momentjs is amazing, I do understand that the user may not want to include a third party library for such) (outputs `Mon Nov 30 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100` to me). Also, keep in mind that it is strictly related to the current locale, hence anyone with some specific locale may not encounter this

Comment: So there is no built-in solution. I have to write my own function to do that. Thanks for the code snippet @briosheje. Sum everything up in a answer if you wish and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Flawyte : I'm not sure there is a built-in solution for that and I don't even know why such happens. To be entirely honest, I think that such may be related to the current locale, because if you consider that GMT +1 currently translates to December 1st the same wouldn't happen with GMT -1, which will translate to November 30th. Though the solution I've provided above works (because it checks whether the new date is actually truly in the previous month) I'm ready to bet that there are cleverer solutions to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var date1 = new Date('2015-12-31');
var date2 = new Date(date1);
date2.setDate(date2.getDate()-date1.getDate()); 
alert(date2)
```

Comment: Simplified it in `date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - date2.getDate());` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: That only works for the last day of the month, so is not really a general solution. There are other days (such as 30 March) that are not the last day of the month and have the same issue, and 29 March that intermittently has it.

Comment: @RobG Yes right but requirement is for End Dates in that case it will work

Comment: @JaydipJ—it does not seem sensible to first work out if this algorithm applies or some other, then apply the appropriate algorithm when there is an algorithm that works in all cases.

Comment: @RobG Yes you are right. Need generic solution , thanks for suggession

Answer (score 1):

When subtracting months, you can check whether the day of the adjusted Date is different to the day of the initial Date. If it is, then it must have rolled over to the next month, so set the day of the adjusted Date to 0, so it goes to the last day of the previous month, e.g.

```js
function subtractMonths(date, months) {
  var day = date.getDate();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - months);
  if (date.getDate() != day) date.setDate(0);
  return date;
}

// 31 Mar 2016 - 1 month = 29 Feb 2015
[[new Date(2016,2,31), 1],

 // 29 Feb 2016 - 12 months = 28 Feb 2015
 [new Date(2016,1,29), 12],

 // 15 Feb 2016 - 3 months = 15 Nov 2015
 [new Date(2016,1,15), 3]].forEach(function(arr){
  document.write('<br>' + subtractMonths(arr[0], arr[1]));
})
```

The same algorithm can be used for adding months. Note that this is why date arithmetic is not symmetric, e.g.

```
31 May + 1 month  => 30 June
30 June - 1 month => 30 May
```

i.e. If A + B = C, then C - B = A may or may not be true (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`setMonth` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth), ‘If you do not specify the [optional] `dayValue` parameter, the value returned from the `getDate()` method is used’. Since you’re not specifying the optional parameter, your code tries to set the date to 2015-11-31, which isn’t valid. JavaScript resolves this situation by setting the date to one day after 2015-11-30, which is 2015-12-01.

As for a workaround, it depends on what you’re actually trying to do. Are you trying to go 31 days back from 31 December?  Or are you trying to get the last day of the month before December?  Date semantics are extremely complicated; what are you going to do when the inevitable edge cases arise?

Comment: Well when you substract one month to the last day of a month, you expect to get the last day of the previous month. At least that is my opinion, and that's what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Please note that MDN is not an authority on ECMAScript, the language specification is, i.e. [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html). The algorithm for *setMonth* is in [*§20.3.4.25*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.setmonth) (which is reasonably well summarised on MDN).

Answer (score 0):

It is producing the requested result, which is subtracting 1 month from the date given. But remember a month is a variable amount of time. November 31 is actually December 1 (just like November 55th  would actually be December 25, Christmas). To get the last day of the previous month you could do something like this:

```
var date = new Date('2015-12-31');
date.setDate(-1)
```