# One date per month of current year till now

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I've built a small function with Javascript to get the date of each month of the current year till now. However it has a loop and crashes Chrome.

```js
function getMonthsInYearTillNow() {
  var today = new Date();
  today = new Date(today.setHours(today.getHours(), 0, 0, 0));
  today_year = today.getFullYear();
  var months = [];

  while (today.getFullYear() === today_year) {
    console.log(today);
    var begin = today;
    begin = new Date(begin.setDate(1));
    begin = new Date(begin.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    var end = today;
    end = new Date(end.setMonth(end.getMonth() + 1));
    end = new Date(end.setDate(0));
    end = new Date(end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 59));
    var cacheobj = {
      'date': today,
      'begin': begin,
      'end': end
    };
    months.push(cacheobj);
    today = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1, 1));
  }
  return months;
}
```

Maybe someone will see the mistake. I can't find it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I want an Array which contains a date object for each month of the current year, till today. In other words from Janaury 2018 to now (Oct-18) e.g.:

```
Array[Date-Object(October),Date-Object(September),..,Date-Object(January)]
```

I change the var 'today' at the end of the while loop with

```
today = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1, 1));
```

I have three other functions for different types of timeranges and they all work, that's why I'am confused and don't find a solution :/

Comment: It crashes because the loop is infinite; you never change either of the year values in the `while` condition. What is the output you're trying to achieve? I'm certain it can be done in a much simpler way

Comment: Thanks for editing, but it's still not clear. Do you want an array of values from now for the next 12 months (ie. Oct-18 to Sep-19) or months remaning in the current year (ie. Oct-18, Nov-18 and Dec-18). Your example ends at January which makes no sense given the description.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'am sorry.. :/ I want an array of values for the past months of the current year. e.g. Oct-18, Sep-18, Aug-18 and so on. In other words: From January 2018 to now .

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, doing `today.getFullYear() === today_year` is same as doing `while` `true === true`, which makes your code to run infinite time

You can do something like this to get your result:

```
function getMonthsInYearTillNow() {
  let i = 0;
  const result = [];
  let isCurrentMonth = false;
  while (!isCurrentMonth) {
    let cacheobj = {
      'begin': new Date(2018, i, 1),
      'end': new Date(2018, i, 1, 23, 59, 59, 59)
    };
    result.push(cacheobj);
    if (i === new Date().getMonth()) {
      isCurrentMonth = true;
    }
    i++;
  };
  return result;
}
console.log(getMonthsInYearTillNow());
```

Comment: Downvote is not mine, but this just describes the problem, it doesn't answer it by offering a solution.

Comment: What result are you exactly looking for?

Comment: You need to ask the OP that, not me. Although note that I already have in the comments. I'd suggest deleting this until the OP has clarified exactly what they're attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but it seems to me, that this solution save every single day? I just want one day per month. To simplify day 1.

Comment: Semantically, using *const* for `const result = []` and `const cacheobj = {...};` doesn't make sense. Sure you can't assign a different array or object, but the array and object are both mutated during execution which is contrary to the concept of a constant. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your time guys.. 
I just transform the while to a for loop and thats it..

```
function getMonthsInYearTillNow() {
        var today = new Date();
        today = new Date(today.setHours(today.getHours(), 0, 0, 0));
        today_year = today.getFullYear();
        var months = [];
        for (var i = today.getMonth(); i >= 0; i--) {
            today = new Date(today.setMonth(i,1));
            console.log(today);
            var begin = today;
            begin = new Date(begin.setDate(1));
            begin = new Date(begin.setHours(0,0,0,0));
            var end = today;
            end = new Date(end.setMonth(end.getMonth() + 1));
            end = new Date(end.setDate(0));
            end = new Date(end.setHours(23,59,59,59));
            var cacheobj = {'date': today, 'begin': begin, 'end': end};
            months.push(cacheobj);
        }
        return months;
    }
```

Thanks for you time and your anwsers :)

Comment: Your function will have issues on the 31st of a month. It already fails around February.

Comment: @RobG Could you tell me why? Because of the end var?

Comment: See [*Subtracting 1 month to 2015-12-31 gives 2015-12-01*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427965/subtracting-1-month-to-2015-12-31-gives-2015-12-01).

Answer (score 0):

This one is more declarative.

```js
const monthNameShort = (month) => month.substring(0, 3);
const getMonthFromString = (monthName) => {
  const date = new Date(Date.parse(monthName + 1, new Date().getFullYear()));
  const lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
  const month = new Date(Date.parse(monthName + 1, new Date().getFullYear())).getMonth() + 1;

  return {
    lastDay,
    month
  };
}

function getMonthsInYearTillNow() {
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  const today = new Date();
  const current_month = today.getMonth();

  return Array.from({
      length: current_month - 1
    })
    .map((_, index) => getMonthFromString(monthNameShort(monthNames[index])))
    .reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc = {
        dayleft: acc.dayleft + cur.lastDay,
        months: [...acc.months, {
          name: monthNames[cur.month - 1],
          days: cur.lastDay
        }]
      }

      return acc;
    }, {
      dayleft: today.getDate(),
      months: []
    });
}

console.log(getMonthsInYearTillNow())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.from

```js
const now = new Date();

const year = now.getFullYear(); // Get the year

const month = now.getMonth() + 1; // Get the month

const months = Array.from(Array(month), (_, i) => new Date(year, i, 1));

console.log(months);
```